# System.AccessViolationException error while using managed wifi to connect to specific bssid

Tags: c#, access-violation, wlanapi, bssid

I'm trying to connect to a wifi-network using bssid and have gone through all links available (including codeplex for managedwifi).  My code is returning the following error:

`System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at WifiExample.Program.WlanConnect(IntPtr clientHandle, Guid& interfaceGuid,
WlanConnectionParameters& connectionParameters, IntPtr pReserved)`

sometimes it throws a SEHException too.

Here is the code snippet:

```
try             
{
  WlanConnect(clientHandle, ref guidd, ref cp, IntPtr.Zero); 
} catch(AccessViolationException e) {
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
}
```

This is the function it calls. Its declared in the same file where i am calling it from.

```
[DllImport("wlanapi.dll")]

    public static extern int WlanConnect(

    [In] IntPtr clientHandle,

    [In] ref System.Guid interfaceGuid,

    [In] ref Wlan.WlanConnectionParameters connectionParameters,

    IntPtr pReserved);
```

My code is based on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/d11150ae-9bb7-4e44-9c57-6a411b9772d7/cant-connect-to-a-specific-ap-using-wlanconnect?forum=vistawirelesssdk).

How can I solve this? Any help would be great!